# What is this insect in my plants?

Tags: houseplants, pests, insects

I was [having some problems](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/59367/what-are-these-white-spots-on-my-plants/59369#59369) with my plants, that somebody identified as thrips.

Just today, I moved one of the pots on my plants, and from underneath I found a lot of tiny insects.

I was able to get one, and take a somehow decent picture of it with a magnifying glass.

[image]

Is this thrips? Based on the pictures I've seen online, they seem to be much more slender, but I also know there are thousands of species.

Does anybody know what this is? Should I be concerned? How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

The insect pictured is not a thrip because it doesn't seem to have wings, though I can't otherwise identify it. Since you found it under a pot, its likely to be an insect  that prefers damp conditions, which is why it was under there.

Comment: I've been thinking about it, and I think that it's unreasonable to expect to have plants, and have zero insects hanging around. This doesn't seem to be a threat for now, so I guess I shouldn't need to do anything about these guys. As somebody return more experience, do you think this is a reasonable analysis?

Comment: I 100% agree with your assessment - unless a plant is heavily infested with, say, aphids or other pests which are causing extreme damage,  a few insects here and there are okay - we share the planet with them, they are part of life here. and insects are incredibly important in the environment... Deciding what an insect is and assessing how damaging it could be before treating with insecticide is ideal.